# Calculating percentage error for sums when there aren't absolute values?

Tags: error-propagation

So, let's say that I measured the lengths of two objects which measured 20 mm and 30 mm. I used the same ruler for both measurements and it has an absolute error of ±1 mm.

If I wanted to calculate the percentage error of the sum of both lengths, correct me if I'm wrong but, it would be this:

$$\text{R%} = \frac{1+1}{20+30}*100$$
$$\text{R%} = 4\text{%}$$

My question is, what if the measurements of those two objects were obtained in a method that involved products or quotients and thus, only an absolute error is provided? i.e. how would I calculate the **percentage error of the sum of the lengths** if I only know their **respective individual percentage errors**? e.g. 20 ± 10% and 30 ± 8%

Could I work backwards in the equation like this to obtain a legitimate absolute error:
$$10\text{%} = \frac{∆d}{20}*100$$
...even though in this example, the 20 mm measurement was hypothetically derived through several product and quotient equations?

Comment: protip: in math mode, use \text{YOUR TEXT} to make your text not look shitty

Comment: The rule is: when adding or subtracting, the absolute error of the sum or difference is the sum of the absolute errors. When multiplying or dividing the relative error of the product/quotient is the sum of the relative errors.